# Chaining .SelectMany() has better performance over using previous in memory collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method for a drilldown chart that gets data based on which column a user clicks. Using Entity Framework 5, my EF classes are as follows (psuedocode):

Parent Class A, 
Class B : A, 
Class C : B, 
Class D : B

So A has many B's, and B can have many C's and D's

The method has a switch for the column clicked, and before the switch statement I loaded the collection of B's since A's are never used on the chart.

```
var bList = _db.ACollection.SelectMany(x => x.BCollection).ToList();
switch (columnClicked)
{
  case B:
    var items = bList.Select(//project to display item for chart);
  case C:
    var items = bList.SelectMany(x => x.CCollection).ToList().Select(//project);
  case D:
    //same as C
}
```

This would take around two seconds to return data (around 40 rows).

I found that instead of using bList, I could just (example: for case C) use

```
_db.ACollection.SelectMany(x => x.BCollection).SelectMany(x => x.CCollection).ToList().Select(//project)
```

for an almost 10 fold speed increase!

Can anyone explain this is?

**Edit (for clarification)**
In case C where I project to a chart detail item, I have a method to call to set the color of the text when it's displayed

```
bList.SelectMany(x => x.CCollection).ToList().Select(c => new ChartDetailitem
{
  // other properties...
  TextColor = SetColor(c.DataColor)
})
```

Comment: try removing `ToList()` when building `bList` at first. You don't need a `List` there, just actually use `ToList()` for each `case`. Also how you estimated out the time `2 seconds`? You should use Stopwatch to benchmark it carefully excluding any before or after time consumed by other code.

Comment: Indeed - importantly, anything *after* `ToList` has to happen locally, whereas if you haven't called `ToList` yet, EF can put further parts of the query into SQL.

Comment: @Hopeless The reason I had ToList() there was because in case B, I had to call some methods to manipulate data when projecting in the select. Also, I have VS2015, so I was just going by the time elapsed thing that shows when debugging.

Comment: @JonSkeet So should I just move the bList into each case, since the last two cases have to have a different collection to use than the first?

Comment: @JB06 if so you of course don't take benefit of server performance here, once you want to modify some property as you said, using L2O locally is your choice. But I'm not sure if you measured the time correctly, don't really think it's so slow, 2 seconds is a large delay indeed (while just 40 rows?), your query is also simple enough. I guess maybe there are some code you've not posted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just move the bList", but you should be able to get rid of the `ToList` call after `SelectMany(x => x.BCollection)`, and I'd *also* remove the one after the other `SelectMany`. Basically, only call `ToList` when you really want to execute the SQL, understanding that anything after that will happen in memory.

Comment: @JonSkeet I use a method while projecting, see edit, so I have to call ToList() before the Select() or I get an exception, since the method won't translate to SQL. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Only that you may want to use a `Select` which creates an instance of an anonymous type with just the properties you'll need later, to avoid pulling irrelevant data.

Comment: I had another parent class list as well, removing the unneeded ToLists seems to have sped it up considerably. I guess I've always had the mindset that in-memory work is fast, but not as fast as server speed, apparently. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @JB06 the server is not always better, sometimes the server is busy and then local computing may be better. Also in this case it involves `SelectMany` which should be done on server for better performance, otherwise there may not be much difference depending on the query itself. But yes most the queries should be done on server as much as possible (especially ones requiring to group, join, order)